# How can i add two numbers in foreach blade in laravel and display the total

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-6, laravel-7

I need to add two numbers passed by the foreach in the blade view
[image]

how can i add this two numbers instead of showing it as individual 333.34 333.34,
I need to show it as 666.68 / 1000 AUD

Here's how blade foreach looks like

```
    @if(!empty($teams)&&count($teams)>0)
@foreach($teams as $key=>$team)

<table>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>Team Name</th>
      <th>Payment</th>
      <th>Time Remaining</th>
      <th>Num of Players Paid</th>
      <th>Paid out of</th>
      <th>Captain Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
      <td>{{$team->name}}</td>
       <td>{{($team->pivot->status==0)?'PENDING':(($team->status==1)?'REGISTERED':(($team->pivot->status==3)?'REMOVED':(($team->pivot->status==2)?'WITHDRAWN':'')))}}</td>
        <td>
          @if ($team->pivot->status == 0)
            {{\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($team->pivot->created_at.' +1 day'))->diffForHumans(null, true, true, 2)}}
          @else
          Registered at {{$team->pivot->updated_at->todatestring()}}
          @endif
      </td>
      <td>{{ $team->competitionPayments->count() . '/' . $team->players->count() .' PAID'}}</td>
      <td>
        @foreach ($team->competitionPayments as $amount)
            {{ $amount->amount }}
        @endforeach
        /

        @foreach ($team->competitions as $total)
        {{ $total->pivot->total_fee .' AUD'}}
        @endforeach
      </td>
      <td>{{$team->captain->full_name}}</td>
      <td>{{$team->pivot->status}}</td>

      {{-- <td>{{($team->pivot->status==0)?'PENDING':(($team->status==1)?'REGISTERED':(($team->pivot->status==3)?'REMOVED':(($team->pivot->status==2)?'WITHDRAWN':'')))}}</td> --}}

    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Full Name</th>
          <th>DOB</th>
          <th>Active Kids Voucher AKV</th>
          <th>Accept Reject AKV</th>
          <th>Paid $</th>
          <th>Paid By </th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>Stripe</th>
          <th>Mobile</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>T&C</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach ($team->players as $player)
      <tr>
          <td>{{ $player->full_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $player->dob }}</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>
              {!!  $player->competitionPayments->isNotEmpty() ?
                implode($player->competitionPayments->map(function($item, $key) {
                    return ($key > 0 ? '<div class="mb-1"></div>' : '') . number_format($item->amount, 2) . ' AUD <br> <hr>' . $item->updated_at->todatestring();
                })->toArray()) : '-' !!}
          </td>
          <td>{{ $player->competitionPayments->isNotEmpty() ? $player->competitionPayments->implode('paidBy.name') : '-' }}</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>{{ $player->mobile }}</td>
          <td>{{ $player->email }}</td>
          <td>-</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
  </table>

  <br><br><hr><br><br>
@endforeach
@else
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <div class="text-muted small text-center">
            No teams have registered yet
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endif
```

Heres the relationship in my `Team model`

```
  public function competitionPayments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CompetitionPayment::class, 'team_id');
}
```

Here's my `controller` function

```
public function detailedRegistrations($competition)
{

    $competitions = $this->competitionsRepo->findOrFail($competition);

    $teams = $competitions->teams()->get();

    $payments = $competitions->payments()->get();

    return view('competitions.detailed-registrations',
                    [
                        'teams'=>$teams,
                        'payments'=>$payments,
                        'competitions'=>$competitions,
                    ]
                );
}
```

I tried to add the `sum()` and get the total as below and i got a wrong total and repeated

```
<td>
    @foreach ($team->competitionPayments as $amount)
        {{ $amount->sum('amount') }}
    @endforeach
    /

    @foreach ($team->competitions as $total)
    {{ $total->pivot->total_fee .' AUD'}}
    @endforeach
  </td>
```

This is the total i got

[image]

Someone please help me out or suggest a way that i could fix this issue

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_sum()` method. Replace this block

```
  @foreach ($team->competitionPayments as $amount)
        {{ $amount->amount }}
    @endforeach
```

With this

```
  @php 
  $temparr = (array) $team->competitionPayments
  @endphp
  {{array_sum(array_column($temparr,'amount'))}}
```

Or directly try

```
  @php 
  $sum = 0
  @endphp
  @foreach ($team->competitionPayments as $amount)
        $sum = $sum + $amount->amount
  @endforeach
```

Comment: it did not work
i got this error:
ErrorException
array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: it didn't work either 
Error : array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have converted object to array now it should work.

Comment: It gave an output of  '0 / 1000 AUD', it does not count  ;(

Comment: Can you just check what are you getting in $temparr ?